# Perl: How to glob all and only subdirectories?

Tags: perl, directory, hidden, traversal, glob

I am trying to write a Perl script that does a preorder directory traversal.  I need it to get all subdirectories of a given directory including the hidden ones.  Unfortunately when I try to glob this way:

<$dir/* $dir/.*>

... the ".*" causes "." and ".." to be returned too, and this messes up my function because it causes an infinite loop.  How do I get *only* the subfolders of $dir, both regular and hidden, and *not* the current or upper-level directory?

For example if my folder is "dir" and it contains these subdirectories:

hello
.hiddendir
"dir with space in name"
".hidden dir with space in name"
dir2

... I want to get an array with just these and not "." or "..".

I don't care if files show up too because I use "if (-d $dir)" later. Is there a way I can test whether an element of the globbed array is equal to the current directory or the parent directory so I can exclude them?

Thanks

Comment: So what's wrong with saying `if (-d $dir && $dir ne '.' && $dir ne '..') { ...` ?

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -MFile::Find::Rule -E'
   say
      for
         File::Find::Rule->directory->in(".");'
```

or

```
perl -MFile::Find::Rule -E'
   say
      for
          grep $_ ne ".",
             File::Find::Rule->directory->in(".");'
```

[File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm)

Answer (score 1):

Just use grep to filter out the . and .. directories:

```
grep { !/^\.{1,2}$/ } <$dir/* $dir/.*>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `read_dir` function in [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSlurp) automatically excludes `.` and `..`, by default.